# Merging arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, merge

Let's say you have three String arrays
for example:

> array1: as,hi,ji
>
> array2: fo,gl
>
> array3: gt,my,wx,zq

As you can see, the individual arrays are sorted.
How would you merge them, with the merged array also being sorted?
I know you can first write a method to merge a pair of them, then merge the final one with this new one.
Mostly I am just confused if you should first merge then sort or vice versa.
Would merge sort be useful?

Comment: Mergesort is more than useful. It is easy to implement, comprehensible, and very effective. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists

Comment: If they are already sorted, you can just use a "Merge" to create the final array, i.e. tak the lowest item left in the 3 three arrays and move it to the output array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge Sort Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735863/merge-sort-java)

Comment: @Jean-RémyRevy:  I don't see how this is a duplicate (anymore).  The link describes merge *sort*, but not how to explicitly merge two arrays together.  You can *definitely* do one without the other.

Comment: Please stop editing your question, it will not help you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like

```
public static String[] join(String[]... sas) {
    String[] result = new String[0];
    for (String[] sa : sas) {
        result = Arrays.copyOf(result, result.length + sa.length);
        System.arraycopy(sa, 0, result, result.length - sa.length, sa.length);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then

```
String[] s = join(s1, s2, s3);
Arrays.sort(s);
```

Maybe there is any external library handling this.

Related the efectivity, sorting the array has complexity **~ N * log N** (merge-sort) which is worse than copying (**~ N**), so the better way is to unite the array and sort once than sort each particular merge. Java class Arrays uses the merge-sort internally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general idea, despite the 3 String arrays are sorted already, I added Arrays.sort() in case the arrays you are using are not sorted

```
String[] a1 = {"as", "hi", "ji"};
String[] a2 = {"fo", "gl"};
String[] a3 = {"gt", "my", "wx", "zq"};

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a1));
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(a3));
String[] all = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
Arrays.sort(all);

for(String a : all) {
   System.out.println(a);
}
```